# Why did I have to use [0][0] with a 2D array for int min rather than just = 0

Tags: java

so my question is, in my code, where it says int min = a2[0][0] why does it have to be like that rather than using int min = 0; when i have that it prints out 0, but [0][0] it prints out the correct answer.. so im just curious as to why that needs to be used? Thanks! :)

```
 public static int min2DArray(int[][] a2) {
        int min = a2[0][0];
        for (int row = 0; row < a2.length; row++) {
            for (int column = 0; column < a2[row].length; column++){
                if (a2[row][column] < 1){
                    min = a2[row][column];
                }
            }
        }
        return min;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code has an error:

```
if (a2[row][column] < 1){
```

should be:

```
if (a2[row][column] < min){
```

---

If your data contains `3, 7, 9` and you initialize `min` to `0`, then none of them are below the initial value and you get `0` as the result.

You *could* initialize `min` to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, and you'd be fine, or you can initialize it to the *first* value, i.e.

```
int min = a2[/*row=*/0][/*column=*/0];
```

Comment: thank you for that catch and that explanation. Very well put! +1

Answer (score 0):

If your 2D array had any negative values, `int min = 0` would be inaccurate. In fact, if anything bigger than 0 were your actual minimum value, your code would not function either. You just have a lucky case where your min is 0.

Comment: well the lowest number is 10 so guess thats why huh? so what exactly is the difference from int min = 0 to int min = a2[0][0]

Comment: As long as there is a smaller value in the array, the initial value of `min` is irrelevant. Only when they're all bigger will the algorithm fail to update `min` (assuming a comparison to `min` instead of 1). The real question is what the comparison to 1 achieves.

Comment: @Andreas Hey, stop pretending to be me. ;-)

Comment: @Andreas I really don't want to come up with a new screen name. Let's pretend this never happened :)